# not getting http referer in varnish cache in req.http.referer

Tags: varnish-4

I am using varnish for caching in my website. Now I have a requirement that I have to show some other slider when the user is redirected from a website other wise I have to show normal one.

As template is getting cached php code is not getting executed.

What I did to achieve this is:

In `vcl_rec` i was checking the `res.http.referer`, I'm not getting the correct referer.... when a user gets redirected from lets say `https://www.example.com` I never get `example.com` in referer.

Comment: Is res.http.referer a typo ? Because it should be req.http.referer

Comment: yes its a typo. sorry for that. its req.http.referer

Comment: Could you post your vcl file ?